# Why are my error bars shifted 1 to the right on the x-axis?

Tags: python, plot, errorbar

I'm trying to plot a scatterplot connected with dashed lines between points and error bars. However, the error bars are plotted next to the dashed lines, shifted +1 on the x axis. How can I shift them back so they overlay?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
#House A
x1=[1, 2, 3]
y1=[44.23777993, 1.412909458, 0.07779971243]    
#House B    
x2=[1, 2, 3]
y2=[6.19927899,1.00263735,0.09018145733]
#House C
x3=[1, 2, 3]
y3=[5.631459288,3.198409548,2.141106453]
#House D
x4=[1, 2, 3]
y4=[1.545221235,0.065499083,0]

#error bar values
#HouseA
y1error=[0.07781274738, 0.394854516, 1.040530416]
#HouseB
y2error=[0.1445699413, 0.4590436542, 1.303785259]
#HouseC
y3error=[0.08168626561, 0.1449873167, 0.1714882825]
#HouseD
y4error=[0.1737233193, 1.1360461, 0]

plt.plot([str(i) for i in x1], y1, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.plot([str(i) for i in x2], y2, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.plot([str(i) for i in x3], y3, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.plot([str(i) for i in x4], y4, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')

#error bars
plt.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=y1error,  color='cornflowerblue', ecolor='k', capsize=8, capthick=0.8)
plt.errorbar(x2,y2,yerr=y2error,color='darkmagenta', ecolor='k', capsize=8, capthick=0.8)
plt.errorbar(x3, y3,yerr=y3error,  color='olivedrab', ecolor='k', capsize=8, capthick=0.8)
plt.errorbar(x4,y4,yerr=y4error, color='goldenrod', ecolor='k', capsize=8, capthick=0.8)

axis_x= range(1,3)
axis_y=range(0,70)
plt.ylim((0,70))
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [8, 6]


plt.show()
```

I tried adding "+1" to x1, but it can't mix int and string
I tried to change xlim to zero

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing ```plt.plot([str(i) for i in x1], y1, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')``` instead of just ```plt.plot(x1, y1, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')``` which will give you what you want (as per my understanding)

Answer (score 0):

When you give `plt.plot` a list of strings it will interpret them as labels and plot them starting from zero. Because your x argument is `['1','2','3']` it will plot at coordinates `[0,1,2]` and use your x argument as labels.

I suspect the reason you did it this way was to limit your tick marks to integer locations. Instead you could try:

```
plt.plot(x1, y1, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.plot(x2, y2, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.plot(x3, y3, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.plot(x4, y4, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```